# Водний і водяний

Tags: різниця-між-словами, пароніми

У [словнику паронімів Гринчишина](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0002860) щодо розрізнення значень *водний* і *водяний* маємо такі значення:

> **Водний** - 1. який стосується водної маси, а також використання води з певною метою, для певних галузей господарства..... **в.культури** - рослини, що можуть вирощуватися в рідкому (водному) поживному середовищі.
>
> **Водяний** - ... 2. Який стосується простору, покритого водою.
> 3. Який живе або росте у воді або на її поверхні. У сполученні: в.лілея, папороть, кропива тощо.

Ці два пояснення дуже важко розрізнити. То з яким з цих двох прикметників сполучати іменники рослина, квітка, коло (наприклад, від кинутого камінця), транспорт...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транспорт *водний*, решта *водянí*. Тобто, *«водяни́й»* у вашому значенні 3 може означати те саме, що й *«водний»*.
Друге слово у вас *«водяни́й»*, та [ще ж є *«во́дяний»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vodjanyj) – *водянистий, багатоводний*:
*во́дяна картопля, во́дяне озеро*.
Ну, тоді вже згадаємо ще про слово [*«во́дявий / водя́вий»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vodjavyj) (можливі обидва варіанти наголосу) – 1. водянистий: *водявий виноград*; 2. безбарвний: *водяві очі*.